# Screen Sharing with the correct scaling/resolution with Retina MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, display, remote-desktop, resolution

I'm trying to use my 13in MBP (2016, 2560x1600) to remote into my Mac Mini that's connected to two 1080p displays, all over my LAN. Using the built in screen sharing, I'm able to do this with acceptable latency, but the scaling is always wrong. My goal is for the remote mac to have the exact same scaling of my native mac (i.e. look the same), but I can't figure out a way to do this.

I'm not able to choose my desired resolution in the display settings and even when I use programs such as DisplayResX that (once I added a custom display profile), let me choose my desired resolution, everything appears far too small on the screen and isn't properly scaled up. The weird thing is that I'm able to use Microsoft Remote Desktop from my mac to connect to windows which just gives me perfect scaling with retina resolution by default (I'm aware that this uses the proprietary RDP) but I can't do so between macs.

Has anyone found any solutions to this? I've tried several 3rd party remote desktop applications (teamviewer, etc.) but most just give me the wrong resolution with black bars or make things blurry at lower resolutions.

Comment: I can’t say for sure this will work in this case, but I have used Jump Desktop https://jumpdesktop.com/ for this and it has an option to match the resolution of the remote machine.

Comment: @TJLuoma that's definitely the best solution I've found so far. I was only able to get it to stretch the screen size for me, but it looks decent after I used SwitchResX to 1280x800 (HiDPI) scaled to 2560x1600.